# AST of a project by Clang

Tags: clang, llvm, abstract-syntax-tree

I use the Clang python binding to extract the AST of c/c++ files. It works perfectly for a simple program I wrote. The problem is when I want to employ it for a big project like openssl. I can run clang for any single file of the project, but clang seems to miss some headers of the project, and just gives me the AST of a few functions of the file, not all of the functions. I set the include folder by -I, but still getting part of the functions.

This is my code:

```
import clang.cindex as cl    
cl.Config.set_library_path(clang_lib_dir)
index = cl.Index.create()
lib = 'Path to include folder'
args = ['-I{}'.format(lib)]
translation_unit = index.parse(source_file, args=args)
my_get_info(translation_unit.cursor)
```

I receive too many header files not found errors.

**UPDATE**

I used Make to compile openssl by clang? I can pass -emit-ast option to clang to dump the ast of each file, but I cannot read it now by the clang python binding.

Any clues how I can save the the serialized representation of the translation units so that I will be able to read it by index.read()?

Thank you!

Comment: What commands you used to get the AST of simple programs ?

Comment: I updated my post with adding my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would "simply" need to provide the right `args`. But be aware of two possible issues.

Different files may require different arguments for parsing. The easiest solution is to obtain [compilation database](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/JSONCompilationDatabase.html) and then extract compile commands from it. If you go this way be aware that you would need to filter out the arguments a bit and remove things like `-c FooBar.cpp` (potentially some others), otherwise you may get something like ASTReadError.

Another issue is that the include paths (`-I ...`) may be relative to the source directory. I.e., if a file `main.cpp` compiled from a directory `/opt/project/` with `-I include/path` argument, then before calling `index.parse(source_file, args=args)` you need to step in (`chdir`) into the `/opt/project`, and when you are done you will probably need to go back to the original working directory. So the code may look like this (pseudocode):

```
cwd = getcwd()
chdir('/opt/project')
translation_unit = index.parse(source_file, args=args)
chdir(cwd)
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, Alex! I proceeded more or less the same structure. I compiled the project with Make. Then it gives me a .d file for every single c file, in which contains include paths. Then I used clang python binding and pass those paths with -I option to args. I can now get the AST of all of the files separately.