# Parsing source file with libclang - problems with linking include files

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, clang++, libclang

I've written a script to parse C/C++ files using the `libclang` library.

The file I was trying to parse: [osf_sys.c](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torvalds/linux/ec8f9ceacef719a844ca269d654502af6a00a273/arch/alpha/kernel/osf_sys.c). The program prints each function/variable etc. in the file. Sample output:

```
...
CURSORKIND: 6; __user at line: 469
CURSORKIND: 43; struct proplistname_args at line: 469
CURSORKIND: 6; nbytes at line: 470
...
```

So I run my script `./script osf_sys.c` and parsing mostly works. However, I notice that certain parts of `osf_sys.c` were not being printed (missing variables and whatnot) and I suspect it had to do with the header files (which were located in a separate directory). I added a code snippet to help with debugging / printing of the error messages shown below.

### Attempt 1

After building the script with `CMake`, I proceed to run it. This is the error that is printed:

```
/Linux_Kernel/linux/arch/alpha/kernel/osf_sys.c:13:10:
fatal error: 'linux/errno.h' file not found
```

It seems like it is having some issues locating the header files of this `osf_sys.c`. So I added this to `CMakeLists.txt` (which is probably wrong since the problem doesn't seem to be with the compilation of my program but with how libclang locates stuff):

```
-I/Linux_Kernel/linux/include
```

Note that the full path of [errno.h](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torvalds/linux/ec8f9ceacef719a844ca269d654502af6a00a273/include/linux/errno.h) is `/Linux_Kernel/linux/include/linux/errno.h`

### Attempt 2

I decided to drag the entire `include/` folder into the same directory that `osf_sys.c` resides in.

Now, running it gives me a new error printout:

```
/Linux_Kernel/linux/arch/alpha/kernel/osf_sys.c:13:10: error:
'linux/errno.h' file not found with <angled> include; use "quotes" instead
```

followed by:

```
/Linux_Kernel/linux/arch/alpha/kernel/linux/errno.h:4:10:
fatal error: 'asm/errno.h' file not found
```

Okay, now it seems to be reading something. Sure enough, the line in question is `#include <linux/errno.h>` from the `osf_sys.c` file.
The second error message occurs presumably because I didn't drag the `asm/` folder into the same working directory as `osf_sys.c`.

### Attempt 3

So, as requested, I manually edit `osf_sys.c` to change `#include <linux/errno.h>` to `#include "linux.errno.h"`

This time, I'm left with the following error message:

```
/Linux_Kernel/linux/arch/alpha/kernel/linux/errno.h:4:10: 
fatal error: 'asm/errno.h' file not found
```

### Attempt 4

Passing `-I/Linux_Kernel/linux/include` as an argument into the script. The script uses the following parameters for the `CXTranslationUnit`:

```
CXTranslationUnit translationUnit = clang_parseTranslationUnit(index, nullptr, argv, argc, 0, 0, CXTranslationUnit_KeepGoing);
```

This yields other kinds of error messages:

```
warning: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
/Linux_Kernel/linux/arch/alpha/kernel/linux/errno.h:4:10: error: 'asm/errno.h' file not found
/Linux_Kernel/linux/include/linux/types.h:4:10: error: 'asm/types.h' file not found
...
```

### What's left to do?

I have little intention of editing all the `#include` statements (in every single the linux kernel file) to use double quotes AND dragging the `include/` folder into every single directory with a `.c` file.

Would appreciate some advice on how to make `libclang` search the `include/` file directory I specify.

Any suggestions / alternatives as to how I can go about solving this?

Comment: You could retry attempt #3 but also add the include directory containing `asm/errno.h`

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I seems to be in the same boat you were.

Answer (score 1):

To parse the source file correctly you have to pass to `clang_parseTranslationUnit` (via argv) all the compilation flags that were used for compilation of the kernel. The easiest way to get all of them is to construct [compilation database](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/JSONCompilationDatabase.html). You could try using [bear](https://github.com/rizsotto/Bear) or look for other tools.
Also, look at similar question: [AST of a project by Clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49102264/ast-of-a-project-by-clang)